# How to configure DSN with oracle 10g in MS Windows 8.1 64-bit

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, odbc, dsn

I've microsoft windows 8.1 64x installed on my machine, i want to configure odbc for oracle 10g but unfortunately there is no 64-bit odbc support for oracle in windows 8.1. I need this to do practical on jdbc type-1 driver.
So, is there any way to add DSN support for oracle in windows 8.1 64x ?

Comment: Use the normal Oracle JDBC driver, the Java JDBC-ODBC bridge has been removed in Java 8 (and it was crappy anyway).

Comment: yea i know to configure Oracle JDBC driver but just for knowledge i'm using type1 driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing ODAC 64bits worked for me:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-090165.html